# Is there a way to search for a document in several collections without having to read them all? Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a set of collections in Firestore that each has n different documents, each one with its particularity, in my application I have a menu that the user can search for a specific document and I must search for that document.

However, the problem lies in this case, I do not know when searching for which collection to look for the document in, so far I am searching all collections to find the document the user wants in himself, I wonder if there is any way to search for a document without knowing exactly what collection it is in but in a way that I don't have to go through the database completely.

Currently I do something like this:

**Search Lot 01 collection:**

**...>search returned the document: then cancel the searches.**

**>search did not return the document, so proceed with the search in Lot 02 ...**

**and so on until you find the document...**

In SQL I would basically have one of these fields as the primary key and search for it, but Firestore is NoSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if there is any way to search for a document without knowing exactly what collection it is in

That's not possible.  All Firestore queries require the name of a single collection (or collection group, where all the subcollections have the same name).

With Firestore, if you want a set of documents to be searchable, then they have to be in a collection with a name that you know ahead of time.  You might have to duplicate data into this known collection to solve this particular problem.  Or, find a database that does allow universal searching, like some full text search engines allow.

Comment: Tks, i opted for change my database structure and "Lot" now is Documents from "Lots", then, i check all the lots and through a different field I get to know if what I'm looking for is there.